# Django: Create a multipage JQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-forms, modal-dialog

I am trying to create some sort of multipage modal dialog with Django/Python and JQuery. I didn't found yet in the web something similar to what i have in mind.

My idea is to show a popup dialog when a user press a button in a webpage, then that user can choose from 3 possible choices that immediately - when pressed - bring him to the next page in the dialog. Here the user can choose one element in a list and then the dialog will close and will show the original webpage with the informations submitted by the user.

I already try to put togheter some code blocks, but till now i didn't obtain good results.

Could someone - at least - tell me the correct process?

Comment: This looks like convoluted to me, at least to me.

Comment: Use $.ajax() functions and then replace modal content on the success callbacks of them.

Comment: @Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy What do you mean?

Comment: There could better usability than that. That is what i felt, YMMV.

Comment: I agree with you but it is a request from a customer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use ajax to bring the form as a popup (use either Bootstrap's or jQuery UI)
- If it's a static form, you can add jQuery code to replace the content when change has been detected in each part, using show and hide or other effects to do this
- Multipart forms in general are called 'form wizards'. Django has a [Form Wizard system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) built in, you might want to use that (especially if the form is dynamic).
- for both simplicity on your development side, and just common sense, I highly recommend that you **Don't** make this automatic. Adding a button to move back and forth within your form is nicer, and also easier to configure `$('mybutton').on('click' yada yada yada...`
- also, [this](http://thecodemine.org/#). And [this](http://www.jquery4u.com/forms/6-jquery-form-wizard-plugins/).

Good luck!